# Send email from Summary Web Part link

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to create an email by clicking on a link in a Summary Link Web Part Tool Part. When I click on the link, I want to create an Outlook email for the user with the address and subject in the email. I am having no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider using a Mailto link and add it to a text web part on SharePoint page.

The link can be formatted as:

```
mailto:<email address>?subject=<subject>&body=<body>
```

The link will call out Outlook client application with a New Email window, “Mail to”, “subject” and “Body” filled.

[image]

References:
[How to add a subject to a mailto anchor in HTML.](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000056.htm)